# Transforming electric field in frequency domain to intensity in frequency domain

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, photonics

I'm currently struggling to convert the electric field to the intensity in the frequency domain.

In principle it seems like I need to do the following:
$$
I(\omega)=\mathcal{F}[I(t)]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt|\mathcal{R}(E(t))|^2e^{-i\omega t}
$$
where
$$
E(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega E(\omega)e^{i\omega t}
$$
with the given electric field $E(\omega)$ in the frequency domain.

This is in the first place not really doable analytically and also not very easy numerically. That's why I wanted to ask if there is a better way to do this transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually remarkably easy. No need to go into the time domain. Use Ohm's law and the [impedance of free space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_of_free_space), $Z_0$ (about 377Ω).

$$I(\omega)= E(\omega)^2 /Z_0 $$

Comment: Okay, but what is then my electric field spectrum consists of deltas? Delta squared is always a bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

Taking square of EM signal in time domain is a pointwise product leading to a convolution in the Fourier domain:
F(x×x)=F(x)∗F(x)

As EM signals are mostly sinosuidal, trigonometric identities defines the change in frequency e.g:

$$cos^2x=1/2(1+cos2x)$$
$$sin^2x=1/2(1−cos2x)$$
or

[image]

From the above formulae, one can see that:

**Trignometric conversions explains the peaks shifts in freq domain. Scalar components yield frequency peaks at reference point**